# What is the probability of this question?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

On a single draw from a deck of playing cards the probability of selecting heart is 1/4 the probability of selecting a black card is 1/2. what is the probability of selecting both a heart and a black card ?

Comment: Depends on how much cards are selected. Only one? Then the probability is $0$. What have you tried thus far? Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level.

Comment: Do you mean that one card chosen is both black and a heart? Or do you mean that you choose two cards, one of which is a heart and one that is black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only select one card, the probability of selecting a heart and a black card is zero since no heart card is black, and no black card is hearts.